# Reflect titleformat in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, books, exercises

I am writing an Exercise book and would like to achieve the following structure:

```
1. First chapter: algebra
   Exercise 1.1
   Exercise 1.2
   ...
2. Indipendenza:
   ...
```

Using this code I get the following about which I'm happy about.

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Esercizio~\thechapter.\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Soluzione~\thechapter.\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{algebre}

\section{} % First 
\subsection{}
test
\section{} % Second 
\subsection{}
\section{} % Third 
\subsection{}


\chapter{indipendenza}

\section{} % First 
\subsection{}
\section{} % Second 
\subsection{}
\section{} % Third 
\subsection{}


\end{document}
```

[image]
However it's not reflected in the ToC
[image]

**Plus.** What if I wanted to do a "First part: Exercises"/"Second part: Solutions", still using the same logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it works as you want! Give a `\titleformat` gives a format for your sections and subsections but taking it apart of the title of your section. This is why you only get the section number as an output on your toc.

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand{\Section}{\section{Esercizio~\thechapter.\thesection}}
\newcommand{\Subsection}{\subsection{Soluzione~\thechapter.\thesection}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{algebre}

\Section % First 
\Subsection{}
test
\Section{} % Second 
\Subsection{}
\Section{} % Third 
\Subsection{}


\chapter{indipendenza}

\Section{} % First 
\Subsection{}
\Section{} % Second 
\Subsection{}
\Section{} % Third 
\Subsection{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: very interesting solution! thank you so much